# Plotting from two different data frames using a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I have two data frames in R, one with data chemical data I collected the other with modeling results.

Data frame 1 (let's call it df1)

```
MgO   SiO2   CaO    FeO Al2O3  Na2O   K2O   MnO Cr2O3   NiO  TiO2   Total                    Comment Location       Type   Depth Data_source
1 36.940 38.340 0.248 27.165 0.007 0.000 0.000 0.478 0.044 0.000 0.055 103.277 117.775 Olivine Core 1-1      Core Groundmass 117.775       Probe
2 35.528 38.275 0.219 28.655 0.013 0.001 0.000 0.271 0.000 0.152 0.056 103.170 117.775 Olivine Core 1-2      Core Groundmass 117.775       Probe
```

Data frame 2 (let's call it df2)

```
 Pressure Temperature     mass        S          H        V       Cp                                       formula    SiO2 TiO2 Al2O3 Fe2O3     FeO      MnO     MgO      CaO Na2O K2O P2O5 H2O Data_source
1      500     1251.25 0.055572 0.137564  -685.8689 0.017108 0.069838 (Ca0.01Mg0.85Fe''0.15Mn0.00Co0.00Ni0.00)2SiO4 39.9248    0     0     0 14.3053 0.287910 45.0991 0.382914    0   0    0   0       MELTS
2      500     1250.25 0.107344 0.265616 -1324.4307 0.033038 0.134865 (Ca0.01Mg0.85Fe''0.15Mn0.00Co0.00Ni0.00)2SiO4 39.9162    0     0     0 14.3500 0.288613 45.0615 0.383735    0   0    0   0       MELTS
```

There are five columns in both data frames with relevant information. Columns SiO2, FeO, MnO, CaO and MgO.I would like to plot the data from df1 as points and the data from df2 as a line on the same plot. I did this successfully using the following code.

```
p <- ggplot(data=NULL, aes(MgO, FeO)) +
  geom_point(data=df1, aes(color=Depth, shape=Location, alpha=.5)) +
  geom_line(data=df2)
```

[image: This produces this beautiful plot.]

My problem is that I thought I could use two for loops to plot all the desired columns against each other, i.e. SiO2 vs CaO, MnO, MgO, and FeO, then CaO vs MnO, MgO ....

To do that I made a list of the desired components

```
Olivine_components <- c('MgO', 'SiO2', 'FeO', 'MnO', 'CaO')
```

Then, wrote my for loops.

```
for (j in 1:5) {
  for (i in 2:5) {
    p <- ggplot(data=NULL, aes(Olivine_components[i], Olivine_components[j])) +
      geom_point(data=df1, aes(color=Depth, shape=Location, alpha=.5)) +
      geom_line(data=df2)
    ggsave (p, filename=paste(Olivine_components[i], "_", Olivine_components[j],
                              "probe_and_MELTS", ".png", sep=""))   
  }
}
```

Instead of getting plots that look like the desired plot, I get this plot [image: I get this plot]

Comment: please check with aes_string!

Comment: Get your data into long format (with `reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::gather`) and don't use for loops. **Definitely** don't try to use `data[, i]` inside aes - use `aes_string` or the more modern styling `aes_()` with character column names instead.

Comment: I used aes_string instead of aes and everything works as I had hoped for. Thanks